# Laravel validate unique if id is the same

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel

I have a table/model that contains multiple albums per user.
Is there a way to say that the column `title` should be unique, but only for the rows that have the same `user_id`?

Example: http://pastebin.com/8dvM4a1T

As you can see in the example, the user with the id of 2 has created 2 albums, with the same title. I don't want that to be allowed, that's why I'm wondering if there's a way to deny that with the validator from Laravel?

I tried this, but that did not work.

```
// Validator
    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'title' => 'required|min:1|max:255|unique:galleries,title,'. Auth::user() -> id .',user_id',
        'description' => 'min:1|max:255'
    ]);
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using 5.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The approach with the default `unique` rule does not work because the rule expects the column value to be passed as the third parameter, so in your case it would check if the `title` column is equal to the `Auth::user()->id` value which is not what you want.

You can create you own custom validation rule by adding the following code to the `boot` method of the `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class:

```
Validator::extend('unique_custom', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    // Get the parameters passed to the rule
    list($table, $field, $field2, $field2Value) = $parameters;

    // Check the table and return true only if there are no entries matching
    // both the first field name and the user input value as well as
    // the second field name and the second field value
    return DB::table($table)->where($field, $value)->where($field2, $field2Value)->count() == 0;
});
```

Now you can use the `unique_custom` (or you can name it whatever you like) rule like so:

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
    'title' => 'required|min:1|max:255|unique_custom:galleries,title,user_id,' . Auth::id(),
    'description' => 'min:1|max:255'
]);
```

The rule expects the parameters to be the following:

- the **1st parameter** to be the table name, which in this case is `galleries`
- the **2nd parameter** to be the field name that is supposed to be unique and for which the value comes from the user input, which in this case is `title`
- the **3rd parameter** to be the second field name that will be added to the query conditions, which in this case is `user_id`
- the **4th parameter** to be the value of the field name passed as the third parameter

Also you can use `Auth::id()` since that is the short form of `Auth::user()->id`.

---

You can read more about Custom Validation rules in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you for explaining it also. Works like a charm too.

Comment: You've very welcome. Also it seems I was wrong about not being able to do that using the default `unique` rule. You can in fact pass additional `field` and `value` parameters to use as a second condition, as @VipindasKS very well pointed out in the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36575405/351330).

Comment: so this work fine in create, but how should we customize this for update function ?

Answer (score 11):

Your code should be something like:

```
'title' => 'unique:galleries,title,NULL,id,user_id,'.Auth::user() -> id.'',
```

Or, you can write a custom rule
[Reference here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-distinct)

Comment: so this work fine in create, but how should we customize this for update function ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.3 and above

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

'email' => Rule::unique('galleries')->where(function ($query) {
     $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
 })
```

Laravel 9

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Rule::unique('galleries')->where(fn ($query) => $query->where('user_id', Auth::id()))
```