# How to force data update on laravel validation custom unique

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

I'm new in laravel. I have a table  with menu_id and title I tried to make this title field unique when have the same menu_id. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574583/laravel-validate-unique-if-id-is-the-same)

But I got problem when update it. Can anyone help please? 
My code

```php
Validator::extend('unique_custom', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    // Get the parameters passed to the rule
    list($table, $field, $field2, $field2Value) = $parameters;

    // Check the table and return true only if there are no entries matching
    // both the first field name and the user input value as well as
    // the second field name and the second field value
    return \DB::table($table)->where($field, $value)->where($field2, $field2Value)->count() == 0;
});

public function updateSubmenu( Request $request) {
    $this->validate( $request, [
            'menu_id' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required|unique_custom:posts,title,menu_id,'.$request->menu_id,
            'order_by' => 'required|integer',
            'description' => 'required'
        ],
        [
            'title.unique_custom' => 'This title already token'
        ]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what problem have you got on update? Some exception?

Edit:
If you couldn't update record if title not changes, you need to add one condition to Validator:

```php
Validator::extend('unique_custom', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    // Get the parameters passed to the rule
    list($table, $field, $field2, $field2Value) = $parameters;

    // If old value not changed, don't check its unique.
    $current = \DB::table($table)->where('title')->first();
    if( $current->{$field} == $value) {
        return true;
    }
    return \DB::table($table)->where($field, $value)->where($field2, $field2Value)->count() == 0;
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I can not update other columns  when the title is not changed.