# Laravel Unique Validation for each user

Tags: php, laravel

I am running into an issue which I assume is simple, but it has me stumpted and I would appreciate any help.

The issue is I want each user to be able to create ads, User 1 can have one ad called "Test Ad" and user two can have one ad called "Test Ad" What is happening right now is the user can only have one ad called "Test Ad" but if user one has created "Test Ad" then user 2 is not able to because validation is returning that it already exists, but it doesn't exist for that user.

Here is my validation code:

```
 'ad_title' => 'unique:ads,ad_title,user_id|required|min:3|max:128,' . Auth::user()->id,
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574583/laravel-validate-unique-if-id-is-the-same

Comment: I found the same, but was curious if that is still the best approach since the post is for 5.2 and I am currently running Laravel 8. Just want to make sure I am using the best approach with the new version of Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use closure function to apply your custom validation requirement.

Try

```php
[
    'ad_title' => [
        'required',
        'min:3',
        'max:128',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            return !! (\DB::table('ads')
                ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
                ->get()
                ->contains('ad_title', $value);
            );
        },
]
```

However the logic for this validation is likely to be required at multiple places then it's better to define a custom rule class https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-rule-objects

Comment: Thanks Donkarnash, this works for me and I will be using this numerous places so I am going to go ahead and define a custom rule class to avoid trying to manage it across numerous files.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5.3 and above

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

'email' => Rule::unique('ads')->where(function ($query) {
     $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
 })
```

Laravel 9

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Rule::unique('ads')->where(fn ($query) => $query->where('user_id', Auth::id()))
```